# Is one generation equal to 100 years?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 15

> **13** And he said unto Abram, Know of a surety that thy seed shall be a stranger in a land that is not theirs, and shall serve them; and
> they shall afflict them **four** hundred years; **14** And also that
> nation, whom they shall serve, will I judge: and afterward shall they
> come out with great substance. **15** And thou shalt go to thy fathers
> in peace; thou shalt be buried in a good old age. **16** But in the
> **fourth** generation they shall come hither again: for the iniquity of
> the Amorites is not yet full.

Are four generations the same as 400 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biblically speaking, a generation is 40 years.  Consider the following verses:

> And the LORD's anger was kindled against Israel, and he made them
> wander in the wilderness **forty years**, until **all the generation**, that
> had done evil in the sight of the LORD, was consumed. (Numbers 32:13,
> KJV)
>
> **Forty years long was I grieved with this generation**, and said, It is a
> people that do err in their heart, and they have not known my ways:
> (Psalm 95:10, KJV)

**The 400 Years' Prophecy**

The 400 years and the four generations are not the same time periods, but they do fully overlap.  The additional time period which overlaps both the 400 years and the four generations is that of the 430 years referenced in Exodus 12:40-41:

> "Now the sojourning of the children of Israel, who dwelt in Egypt, was
> four hundred and thirty years.  And it came to pass at the end of the
> four hundred and thirty years, even the selfsame day it came to pass,
> that all the hosts of the LORD went out from the land of Egypt."
> (Exodus 12:40-41)

What challenges many people in understanding these passages, ironically, is the definition of "Egypt."  At its zenith, during the times of Abraham, "Egypt" was a vast empire that included the lands of Canaan and Israel as well.  It afterward got smaller, and by the time Jacob took his family to "Egypt", he "entered" a much-reduced territory which still pertained to Egypt--entering from what, in his grandfather's day, had been part of Egypt as well.  In a sense, then, the family, which had already been in Egypt, "re-entered" the land, even though they had never actually left that territory from the time of Abraham onward--its political boundary had simply receded from them.

With that in mind, let's look more closely at the times again.

#### The 400 Years versus the 430 Years

To Abraham had been given the promise:

> And he said unto Abram, Know of a surety that thy seed shall be a
> stranger in a land that is not theirs, and shall serve them; and they
> shall afflict them four hundred years;  And also that nation, whom
> they shall serve, will I judge: and afterward shall they come out with
> great substance.  (Genesis 15:13-14)

When was Abraham given this promise?  He received this promise before he had had any children, so the clock on the four-hundred years' prophecy could not possibly have started yet.  In fact, this was a special promise to Abraham because it confirmed to him that he *would* have a child.

How old was Abraham when he entered "Egypt"?

> Now the LORD had said unto Abram, Get thee out of thy country, and
> from thy kindred, and from thy father's house, unto a land that I will
> show thee:  And I will make of thee a great nation, and I will bless
> thee, and make thy name great; and thou shalt be a blessing: And I
> will bless them that bless thee, and curse him that curseth thee: and
> in thee shall all families of the earth be blessed. So Abram departed,
> as the LORD had spoken unto him; and Lot went with him: **and Abram was
> seventy and five years old when he departed out of Haran.**  (Genesis
> 12:1-4)

It was at that time, when Abram was 75 years old, that, having left Haran, he entered "Canaan", at that time annexed by Egypt.  So the 430 years' reference dates from Abraham's entry into Egypt.

How old was Abraham when he had a son?

> "And Abraham was an hundred years old, when his son Isaac was born
> unto him." (Genesis 21:5)

So, his "seed" (Isaac) was born to him 25 years after his entry into "Egypt".  But when did the affliction or bondage begin?  It did not begin yet when Isaac was too young to be exposed to anyone much beyond his mother's arms.  But when Isaac was five years old, a weaning party was held for him:

> "And the child grew, and was weaned: and Abraham made a great feast
> the same day that Isaac was weaned.  And Sarah saw the son of Hagar
> the Egyptian, which she had born unto Abraham, mocking.  Wherefore she
> said unto Abraham, Cast out this bondwoman and her son: for the son of
> this bondwoman shall not be heir with my son, even with Isaac."
> (Genesis 21:8-10)

Notice that Isaac was bullied by "the son of Hagar **the Egyptian**."  As Abram had been sojourning in Egypt, the hired maid whom Sarai had given him for the role of surrogate mother, had been Egyptian.  And it was at this point that the prophecy's 400 years began, for at this point the "affliction" part had begun.  The years of "bondage" were yet future.

#### The Four Generations

> "And God spake unto Israel in the visions of the night, and said,
> Jacob, Jacob. And he said, Here am I.  And he said, I am God, the
> God of thy father: fear not to go down into Egypt; for I will there
> make of thee a great nation:  I will go down with thee into Egypt; and
> I will also surely bring thee up again: and Joseph shall put his hand
> upon thine eyes."  (Genesis 46:2-4)

During the famine, when Jacob, at Joseph's special invitation, had brought all of his family into "Egypt," the count began on the four generations.  We can see those generations recorded in the Bible.  While all of Jacob's sons are mentioned, we'll follow the line of Levi:

> "And these are the names of the children of Israel, which came into
> Egypt, Jacob and his sons: Reuben, Jacob's firstborn.  . . . And the
> sons of Levi; Gershon, Kohath, and Merari."  (Genesis 46:8,11)

> "And these are the names of the sons of Levi according to their
> generations; Gershon, and Kohath, and Merari: and the years of the
> life of Levi were an hundred thirty and seven years. . . . And the
> sons of Kohath; Amram, and Izhar, and Hebron, and Uzziel: and the
> years of the life of Kohath were an hundred thirty and three years.
> . . . And Amram took him Jochebed his father's sister to wife; and she
> bare him Aaron and Moses: and the years of the life of Amram were an
> hundred and thirty and seven years.  . . . These are that Aaron and
> Moses, to whom the LORD said, Bring out the children of Israel from
> the land of Egypt according to their armies.  These are they which
> spake to Pharaoh king of Egypt, to bring out the children of Israel
> from Egypt: these are that Moses and Aaron." (Exodus 6:16, 18, 20,
> 26-27)

> And Moses was content to dwell with the man: and he gave Moses
> Zipporah his daughter.  And she bare him a son, and he called his name
> Gershom: for he said, I have been a stranger in a strange land.
> (Exodus 2:21-22)

Summarizing those verses we have:

```
Jacob   --> The patriarch who brought his children and 
            grandchildren to "enter" (re-enter) Egypt;
Levi    --> Entered Egypt, Jacob's son;
Kohath  --> Entered Egypt, the first generation,
            Levi's son;
Amram   --> The second generation, Kohath's son; and
Moses   --> The third generation, Amram's son, 
            who led the Israelites back out of Egypt.
Gershom --> The fourth generation, Moses' son,
            representing the generation brought out of Egypt.
```

The total time from entry into Egypt to departure in the fourth generation may have been around 215 years--half of the 430-year total from Abraham's first entry to the exodus.  But the time for actual hard bondage (slavery) would have been closer to 90 years--just under a century.  We know that Moses was 80 years old at the time he led the people out of Egypt, and the Israelites had been in bondage during Moses' entire lifetime at that point, plus a few years before he was born.

Remember, it was not until after the time of Joseph (after the second generation, post-entry), that the slavery had begun--by an Egyptian king who had not known Joseph.  In other words, the slavery began during the third generation, post-entry, and ended when the fourth generation departed in the exodus.

**Conclusion**

As shown above, the 400 years prophesied included both years of affliction and years of bondage (slavery).  While it is a common misconception that it must have been 400 years of *bondage only*,  God is good, and merciful, and did not suffer His people to remain in bondage for four full centuries as common slaves.  Only a portion of this time was spent in slavery.

Answer (score 0):

Let us remind ourselves of some of the chronology of the history from Abraham to Moses:

- Abraham moves from Haran to Canaan at age 75, Gen 12:4
- Isaac born to Abraham at the age of 100, Gen 21:5
- Isaac marries Rebekah at age 40, Gen 25:20
- Isaac becomes the father of Jacob at age 60, Gen 25:26
- Jacob (at age 71) deceives Isaac when he is 131, Gen 47:9, 45:6, 41:47
- Jacob returns from Padam Aram after 20 years at age 91, as Joseph is born, Isaac 151.
- Joseph is sold into slavery at age 17 (Gen 37:2), Jacob is 108, Isaac is 168.
- Isaac dies at age 180, Gen 35:28.
- Jacob moves to Egypt at age 130, Gen 47:9 during the second year of famine when Joseph is 39 years old.
- Jacob dies at age 147, Gen 47:28

Thus, there were 215 years between Abraham's promise in Gen 12 and Jacob moving to Egypt.  There were 430 years between Jacob moving to Egypt and the Exodus, Ex 12:40, 41, Gal 3:17.

Further there were more than four generation between Abraham and Moses:

- Abraham was the father of Isaac
- Isaac was the father of Jacob
- Jacob was the father of Levi and his 12 borthers including Joseph
- Levi was the father of Gershom and Kohath (Ex 6:16)
- Gershom was the father of Amram who married Jochebed (Ex 6:18, 20)
- Amram was the father of Moses and Aaron (Ex 6:20)
- Moses was the father of Gershom, Ex 2:22

Thus, there were four generation between Abraham and the entry to Egypt: Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, Levi and the 12 brothers.

There were also four generations that lived in Egypt before the Exodus: Levi, Gershom, Amram, Moses.

The prophecy of 400 years (a round number that is not exact) in Gen 15 was made a few decades after Abraham had moved to Canaan (and been to Egypt) Gen 12.  The four generation of Gen 15 is clearly the four generations that lived in Egypt for 215 years before the Exodus.

By this calculation, each generation lasted about 50 years - Moses was in his 70s when his first son was born and 80 when his second son was born.  Other generation were not as old.  Joseph had his two sons in his 30s.